# Override padding css for mobile

Tags: css

I have an padding for body (desktop) but i need to change it to fit at mobiles

this is the body css:

```
    .column{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    max-height:376px;
    padding-left:10%;
}
```

and this is the part for mobile at the same css file:

```
@media all and (max-width : 480px) {
    .column{
        padding-left:-5%;
    }
}
```

why this didn't change anything?

Comment: you cannot have negative padding...

Comment: are you trying to do `10%-5%`???????

Comment: ahahah yes i was trying that, I'm a java developer so web is new for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the padding to 0px on mobile and then add a negative margin if you are looking to move the .column element to the left.

```
    @media all and (max-width : 480px) {
      .column{
          margin-left: -5%;
          padding-left:0;
      }
    }
```